# Fully utilizing MVC Owin identity with n(3)-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I've been learning out of the box [Owin Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) and I love the ease of use it provides us with user management. Then problem that I have is that it interacts directly with EF (seemingly) via `ApplicationDbContext` which I don't want. I would prefer to utilize my 3 tier architecture, IE it interacts with a service layer (BLL) which interacts with EF. I can't find a template, tutorial, or even starting point to maintain all the functionality that is provided and achieve the separation I want.

So is there a way to use a service layer in place of the `ApplicationDbContext` in MVC Identity package.

Comment: Do you want to use ASP.Net Identity with custom tables?

Comment: @Win I want to use the database that my DAL layer is using, with a table names `User`, but I am fine with the column names that are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use existing database/tables, you do not have to use entire ASP.Net Identity. Instead, you can just use ***Owin Cookie Authentication middleware***.

I have working sample code at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin). If you want to test it, you just set a break-point at [AccountController.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L37), and return true.

The followings are two main classes of configure the middleware and sign-in.

### [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Startup.cs)

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
      {
        AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
      });
   }
}
```

### [OwinAuthenticationService.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs)

```
public class OwinAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
    private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

    public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SignIn(User user)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
            };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool so using this I'll just utilize my BLL in the `OwinAuthenticationService`? Then from there I can add things like register, email validation, sms validation, etc. I'm using individual account which was my reason for trying to keep the features intact, like the generated `AccountController`

Comment: You will need to replace [ActiveDirectoryService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L37) with your service which basically authenticate user's credential and return true or false.