# Authentication / Authorization with Cookies, without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a web app in MVC 5 - but don't yet have a way to authenticate or authorize users.

I am using dapper.net for the repository layer.

I do not want to use ASP.NET Identity because it is too complex and tightly coupled to Entity Framework.

I want to use Cookies so users can remain logged in between visits - for months.

Basic Authentication doesn't support cookies and although I will be using SSL seems insecure.

Forms Authentication appears to be being deprecated.

I would like to use Authentication Filters / Attributes.

I just want a simple solution that lets me control how things work.

Is this possible? How can I go about this?

Comment: Identity isn't coupled to EntityFramework

Comment: Not sure if it helps you, but I made for myself [a minimal implementation of cookie authentication with MVC5 and ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/jennings/AspNetIdentityExamples/tree/master/CookieAuthentication), so I can use it as a reference when I need it.

Comment: Identity or roll your own using Forms Authentication. Also Forms authentication is not depreciated and there are no plans to depreciate it, I am not sure where you got (bad) info that from.

Comment: Second @Shoe. Identity is ORM agnostic and it's not complex either. What *is* complex is rolling your own authentication/authorization, as your solution will either become just as "complex" as you think Identity is, or more likely, it will be full of security holes and missing important features.

Comment: @niico You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471014/fully-utilizing-mvc-owin-identity-with-n3-tier-architecture/41471610#41471610).

Comment: @Igor Forms Authentication is being deprecated / replaced with other approaches: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284380/is-formsauthentication-obsolete

Comment: @Shoe OK but if you install identity with a new project - it's all entity framework code - and that requires work to pull it all out.

Comment: @niico then start with an empty project

Comment: @Shoe build the database and everything myself - it's on option but not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Custom Authentication Filter in MVC